# extract first instance per line (maybe grep?)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, awk, sed, grep

I want to extract the first instance of a string per line in linux. I am currently trying grep but it yields all the instances per line. Below I want the strings (numbers and letters) after "tn="...but only the first set per line. The actual characters could be any combination of numbers or letters. And there is a space after them. There is also a space before the tn=

Given the following file:

```
hello my name is dog tn=12g3 fun 23k3 hello tn=1d3i9 cheese 234kd dks2 tn=6k4k ksk

1263 chairs are good tn=k38493kd cars run vroom it95958 tn=k22djd fair gold tn=293838 tounge
```

Desired output:

```
12g3

k38493
```

Comment: Do you REALLY want the `kd` removed from the end of `tn=k38493kd` in your 2nd line of output? If so clarify your requirements, if not fix your expected output.

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way you can do it if you have GNU grep, which (mostly) supports Perl Compatible Regular Expressions with `-P`. Also, the non-standard switch `-o` is used to only print the part matching the pattern, rather than the whole line:

```
grep -Po '^.*?tn=\K\S+' file
```

The pattern matches the start of the line `^`, followed by any characters `.*?`, where the `?` makes the match non-greedy. After the first match of `tn=`, `\K` "kills" the previous part so you're only left with the bit you're interested in: one or more non-space characters `\S+`.

As in [Ed's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38834216/2088135), you may wish to add a space before `tn` to avoid accidentally matching something like `footn=...`. You might also prefer to use something like `\w` to match "word" characters (equivalent to `[[:alnum:]_]`).

Comment: Ah nice, I played with `grep -Po '(?<=tn=)\w' file`, which worked but gave all matches in a line. I like how this works.

Answer (score 0):

Just split the input in `tn=`-separators and pick the second one. Then, split again to get everything up to the first space:

```
$ awk -F"tn=" '{split($2,a, " "); print a[1]}' file
12g3
k38493kd
```

Comment: Regarding the multi-char FS, any POSIX-compliant awk should support that. The GNU-specific behaviour related to RS.

Comment: @TomFenech oh, good to know! I see it is kind of described in the [POSIX awk page](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/awk.html). Thanks

Comment: That will fail if `footn=27` appears before `tn=35` in the input.

Comment: @EdMorton there is no `footn=27` the data would have `foo tn=27` with spaces only.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk 'match($0,/ tn=[[:alnum:]]+/) {print substr($0,RSTART+4,RLENGTH-4)}' file
12g3
k38493kd
```

Comment: Uhms, but what if the line starts with `tn=23`? The leading space in the regexp will make it to not match. It is probably worth using [`\<`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/GNU-Regexp-Operators.html) and say `awk 'match($0,/\<tn=[[:alnum:]]+/) {print substr($0,RSTART+3,RLENGTH-3)}' file`.

Comment: The OP said `There is also a space before the tn=`. Use of `\<` would make it unnecessarily gawk-specific.